# Create a temp table based on the xml data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an xml data as shown in the image,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4brAG.png)
I cannot run the query to create temp table with the column names because the name and number of columns are not fixed so I cannot hardcode the column names in create table query. So, I would have to pick the elements which are coming in the xml data and insert them in the temp table.

I want to insert the above data in a temp table without hardcoding the column names.

The XML (in readable format):

```xml
<LocationsData>
  <Row>
    <AccountId>1</AccountId>
    <ActivityId>3</ActivityId>
    <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <AccountId>2</AccountId>
    <ActivityId>5</ActivityId>
    <CountryCode>AU</CountryCode>
  </Row>
</LocationsData>
```

Comment: Please do not post data as an image (see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.))

Comment: It will be impossible to use that (temp) table, when these requirements keep up, because you will not know the column names in it.

Comment: *I want to insert the above data in a temp table without hardcoding the column names.* Dynamic SQL (prepared statement) - no variants.

Answer (score -1):

Anyway, reading the tags from the XML is no problem:

```
SET @xml = '<LocationsData>
  <Row>
    <AccountId>1</AccountId>
    <ActivityId>3</ActivityId>
    <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <AccountId>2</AccountId>
    <ActivityId>5</ActivityId>
    <CountryCode>AU</CountryCode>
  </Row>
</LocationsData>';

select @xml;

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT
    1 as q,
    SUBSTRING(@xml,INSTR(@xml,'>')+1) as xml,
    SUBSTRING(@xml,INSTR(@xml,'<')+1) as s,
    SPACE(2000) as w
  union all
  SELECT
   q+1,
   SUBSTRING(xml,INSTR(xml,'>')+1),
   SUBSTRING(xml,INSTR(xml,'<')+1),
   SUBSTRING(s,1,INSTR(s,'>')-1)
  FROM cte
  WHERE q<25
  )
SELECT DISTINCT c1.w 
FROM cte c1
WHERE RTRIM(w)<>'' AND LEFT(w,1)<>'/';
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/8DCt7BZk)
output:

| w |
| --- |
| LocationsData |
| Row |
| AccountId |
| ActivityId |
| CountryCode |

Problems start when you are trying to use the MySQL function [ExtractValue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) to get the values from your XML:

this should, IMHO, return 1:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(@xml,'//AccountId[1]');
```

But in fact it's returning: `1 2`   ?